# Failed Request Tracing Module vs Tracing Module

Tags: iis, iis-8

What is the difference between the Failed Request Tracing module and the Tracing module?

Answer (score 0):

The Failed Request Tracing module is part of the Tracing module, under the Health and Diagnostics role service. You need to have the Tracing role service installed to be able to use FRT.

As you can see [here](http://www.trainsignal.com/blog/iis-7-troubleshooting), you will need to go through the installation steps to use FRT.

Comment: So, FRT is a part of the Tracing module. If that is right, why is TracingModule not a dependancy of the FRTModule (see Module list here : http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/introduction-to-iis/iis-modules-overview). Also, Is there any way I could install the TracingModule without the FRTModule, and is there any reason I would want to do that anyway?